# CSS "Multiple Submit button" Question

Tags: css, button, submit

Ok,
I hope this doesnt make me look too dumb but here we go.

I am using Wordpress. I have installed a custom theme. The theme is rendering my forms with a submit button that is a image that wont work. My goal is to figure out a way to get a real submit button or form of, without affecting the other places where its being used in the template. Any suggestions would be awesome. Thanks!

Edited to add code from the OP's comments (below):

```
<form class="fm-form" method="post" action="" name="fm-form-1" id="fm-form-1">
    <h3>Get Your Free Week Pass Here!</h3>
    <ul>
        <li class="text">
            <label>First Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="text-4db09a31c511b" id="text-4db09a31c511b" value="" style="width:300px;">
        </li>
        <li class="text">
            <label>Last Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="text-4db09a656e940" id="text-4db09a656e940" value="" style="width:300px;">
        </li>
        <li class="text">
            <label>Email</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="text-4db09a714f6bc" id="text-4db09a714f6bc" value="" style="width:300px;">
        </li>
        <li class="text">
            <label>Phone Number</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="text-4db09a7bda3ae" id="text-4db09a7bda3ae" value="" style="width:300px;">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" name="fm_form_submit" class="formSubmitButton" value="Submit" onclick="return fm_validate(1)">
    <input type="hidden" id="fm-submit-nonce" name="fm-submit-nonce" value="776fd50811">
    <input type="hidden" name="fm_id" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: What's the (x)html of this Wordpress form, specifically the part containing the submit button.

Comment: <form class="fm-form" method="post" action="" name="fm-form-1" id="fm-form-1">
<h3>Get Your Free Week Pass Here!</h3>
<ul>
<li class="text"><label>First Name</label><br><input type="text" name="text-4db09a31c511b" id="text-4db09a31c511b" value="" style="width:300px;"></li>
<li class="text"><label>Last Name</label><br><input type="text" name="text-4db09a656e940" id="text-4db09a656e940" value="" style="width:300px;"></li>
<li class="text">

Comment: <label>Email</label><br><input type="text" name="text-4db09a714f6bc" id="text-4db09a714f6bc" value="" style="width:300px;"></li>
<li class="text"><label>Phone Number</label><br><input type="text" name="text-4db09a7bda3ae" id="text-4db09a7bda3ae" value="" style="width:300px;"></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" name="fm_form_submit" class="formSubmitButton" value="Submit" onclick="return fm_validate(1)">
<input type="hidden" id="fm-submit-nonce" name="fm-submit-nonce" value="776fd50811"><input type="hidden" name="fm_id" value="1">
</form>

Comment: I added a new class in the style sheet and put a button there which did work but couldnt figure out how to get any text in there. Oh well. It works I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well add to your submit button some specific id (ex: submit_btn) that is used only for submit buttons that you want and then use css:

```
input[type="submit"]#submit_btn { css }
```

Comment: If you're referencing by an ID, all the rest shouldn't matter: `#submit_btn` should do the same as `input[type="submit"]#submit_btn`